# Inputfield with PHP variable and prepared sql not editable

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have many HTML inputs which are filled by an prepared sql statement. The sql-results are inserted in the value-attribute of the `input`. My problem is: When I edit the text of the inputfields (in the Browser, as every user would do) the text in the inputfield changes but when I read the value of this input via `$_POST["id of the inputfield"]` I get the value of the prepared sql.

**For example**

1. The SQL outputs `TextFromSQL` into the inputfield with the id `Input`
2. The users changes the inputfield text to `TextFromMe`
3. The PHP gets with `$_POST["Input"]` the string `TextFromSQL`

I found out (via Google Chrome -> Console -> Elements) that the value-attribute of the input doesn't change but the text which the user can see changes.

**Code (groups/group_edit.php)**

This is the first page where the user can select the group he want to edit.

```
echo'
<div class="modul_padding_scroll">
    <script>
        $(".submit_edit_group_1").click(function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            $.post("groups/group_edit2.php", 
                {
                    group_id: $this.attr("group_id")
                },
                function(data) {
                    $(".ajax_response").html(data);
                }
            );
        });
    </script>
    <span class="modul_span_title">Edit a group</span><br><br>
    <div class="ajax_response2"></div>
    <div class="ajax_response"></div>
        <table class="table_standard">
            <tr>
                <th class="th_titlebar" colspan="4">All groups</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="th_subtitle" style="width:5%;">ID</th>
                <th class="th_subtitle" style="width:20%;">Group</th>
                <th class="th_subtitle">Description</th>
                <th class="th_subtitle" style="width:10%;">Edit</th>
            </tr>';
        $ergebnis = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT group_id, group_name, group_desc FROM groups ORDER BY group_id");
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_object($ergebnis)) {
            echo'
            <tr>
                <td class="td_contentbar">'.$row->group_id.'</td>
                <td class="td_contentbar">'.$row->group_name.'</td>
                <td class="td_contentbar">'.$row->group_desc.'</td>
                <td class="td_contentbar">
                    <button class="inputbutton submit_edit_group_1" group_id="'.$row->group_id.'">Edit</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            ';
        }
echo'   </table>
    </div>';
```

**Code (groups/edit_group2.php)**

In this file the user gets the name and the description of the group he had selected in the first file. These values go into a inputfield where he can edit these values.

```
$input_group_id = $_POST["group_id"];

$sql = $db->prepare("SELECT group_id, group_name, group_desc FROM groups WHERE group_id = ?"); 
$sql->bind_param('i', $input_group_id);
if ($sql->execute()) { 
    $sql->store_result(); 
    $sql->bind_result($group_id, $group_name, $group_desc); 
    $sql->fetch();

echo'
<script>
    $(".submit_edit").click(function() {
        $.post("groups/group_edit3.php", 
            {
                group_id: $("#group_id").val(),
                group_name: $("#group_name").val(),
                group_desc: $("#group_desc").val()
            },
            function(data) {
                $(".ajax_response2").html(data);
            }
        );
    });
</script>
<input type="text" maxlength="50" disabled value="'.$group_id.'">
<input type="hidden" maxlength="50" id="group_id" value="'.$group_id.'">
<input type="text" maxlength="50" id="group_name" value="'.$group_name.'" required></td>
<input type="text" maxlength="50" id="group_desc" value="'.$group_desc.'" required></td>
<input class="submit_edit" type="submit" value="Edit Group"></td>
';
}
```

**Code of the 2nd PHP file (groups/edit_group3)**

```
$input_group_id = $_POST["group_id"];
$input_group_name = $_POST["group_name"];
$input_group_desc = $_POST["group_desc"];

echo $input_group_id.'<br>';
echo $input_group_name.'<br>';
echo $input_group_desc.'<br>';
exit;
```

**UPDATE 1**

I replaced the `<input type="submit"...` now with `<button class="inputbutton submit_edit">Edit group</button>`

**UPDATE 2**

I added the code of the first page (edit_group.php)

**UPDATE 3**

I think the problem is between the `group_edit.php` and the `group_edit2.php` because if I take only the `group_edit2.php` and manipulate the post-variable it works.

Comment: since you're using JS/Ajax, try a `<button>` rather than an input.

Comment: unfortunately it didn't solved the problem

Comment: try `<button type="submit" class="inputbutton submit_edit">Edit group</button>`

Comment: `type="submit"` didn't solved the problem too

Comment: Try wrapping your `$(".submit_edit").click(function() {...});` in a `$(function(){...});` as it might be binding your `.val()` to initial page load values, and not the changed values once the page has loaded.

Comment: This didn't work but I added the code of the first file which I forgot to post, maybe this helps.

Comment: Console.log the data you are sending. 'Console.log(group_id);'. Or which ever one you think is suspect. Do this after the submit event. What value do you get? Correction: do it after you declare it.

Comment: Odd you do not get the value. Can you not set the input 'text ()'; to display the content to be edited? Instead of manipulating the value. This Then leaves the value free.

Comment: @FintanCreaven WIth `$("#group_name").text("'.$group_name.'");` I get an empty inputfield plus an empty ajax-response. The group_id works finde because it is not editable. UPDATE: Even if I let the database-part out of the code, the value is still the value of the value-attribute. If the value-attribute is empty the ajax-response will be also empty, in any case.

Comment: Also something strange is: if I use `#submit_edit` for the click-event, it doesn't get that this id is clicked.

Comment: Have you solved this?

Comment: Nope, im thinking about completly rewriting this section :/

Answer (score 1):

HTML form:   Likes to have the `name` field. Yours don't

```
<form action="welcome.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

PHP file contains:

```
<html>
<body>

Welcome <?php echo $_GET["name"]; ?><br>
Your email address is: <?php echo $_GET["email"]; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

note it uses the `name` given to the input field that came along with the Submit.

Comment: The OP is using jquery to submit the form elements, so `name` attributes are not needed, only needed if submitting via traditional form post.

Comment: Also, it is odd that you show a html form with `method="post"` but your php code has `$_GET`

Comment: *Hm...* OP's using JS/Ajax with their respected ID's. Shouldn't be the issue here Drew.

Comment: Is the insert working correctly. If your inserting into your database and it is unsuccessful your select will not behave as expected. Have you logged at which point it changes. But a'console.log ' of thefield of interest just after the burton click will see if the value is being inserted.

Comment: @FintanCreaven I think you want to cut and paste that into a comment above under the question, not down here under my lame answer, then delete it down here

Comment: Apologies my phone is not behaving. Does the value get passed on button click. Console.log after click event.

Comment: just enter your comments above not down here. Go North ^^^^

Comment: @FintanCreaven I've added `console.log($("#group_desc").val());` to the click-event and the console dispalyed the value which was in the database not the value which I had entered

Answer (score 0):

I get the value of the button clicked as below: It different to yours in the way that I do not have a database table so could not echo the table out

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>


            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script> 
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
      </head>
      <body>
      <div class="modul_padding_scroll">

        <span class="modul_span_title">Edit a group</span><br><br>
        <div class="ajax_response2"></div>
        <div class="ajax_response"></div>
            <table class="table_standard">
                <tr>
                    <th class="th_titlebar" colspan="4">All groups</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th class="th_subtitle" style="">ID</th>
                    <th class="th_subtitle" style="">Group</th>
                    <th class="th_subtitle">Description</th>
                    <th class="th_subtitle" style="">Edit</th>
                </tr>

                                                      <tr>
                    <td class="td_contentbar">3</td>
                    <td class="td_contentbar">a group name3</td>
                    <td class="td_contentbar">a group description3</td>
                    <td> <button type="button" class="inputbutton submit_edit_group_1" id="3">Edit</button></td>
                    </tr>

            </table>


    <script>
            $(".submit_edit_group_1").click(function() {
                 //e.preventDefault();

                var myid = $(this).attr("id");
                console.log(myid); //i get 3


                $.post("group_edit2.php", 
                    {
                        group_id: myid

                    },

                    function(data) {
                        $(".ajax_response").html(data);
                    }
                );
            });
        </script>
```

This will get the id of the button clicked. I just echoed it back on to the page with:

```
<?php

$input_group_id = $_POST["group_id"];
echo $input_group_id;
```

You can add your other ids to the data post but it works. Your other code looks okay. My only other suggestion is that you may need to traverse the dom a bit on your click action. Your are using inputs without forms etc so a:

```
$(td .submit_button)
```

You could also try :

```
$(document).on('click', '.yourbutton', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); //this prevents the submit action and is in all my scripts where a button has a submit attribute

 var myid = $(this).attr("id");
            console.log(myid); //i get 3


            $.post("group_edit2.php", 
                {
                    group_id: myid

                },

        function(data) {
        $(".ajax_response").html(data);
                }
            );
        });
    </script>
```

The post concentrates on one of your scripts but can be used on all with just variable changes.